# Questions About javascript code for image gallery

Tags: javascript, image, gallery

I am trying to understand this javascript-code I got that I'm supposed to use for a image gallery.

I've tried searching but I didn't find anything that was useful for me. I am fairly new to the javascript language.

I like to get help with understanding how exactly I get this code to show the pictures in the HTML document. What do I write in the html?

```
var imgArray = ["pic1.jpg" , "pic2.jpg" , "pic3.jpg", "pic4.jpg"];
var galleryString = "";

for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
GalleryString += "<img src=\" " + imgArray[i] + "\" />";
}

document.getElementById("galleryDiv").innerHTML = galleryString;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a typo: `GalleryString` should be `galleryString`. JavaScript identifiers are case-sensitive, so `GalleryString` and `galleryString` are different variables. Once you fix that, you should see all images from `imgArray` inside your `galleryDiv`.

Comment: I'm still not able to get the gallery to display any pictures.
I've made a div with the ID "galleyDiv". Is there anything else I'm supposed to do for it to work? 

I'm still searching for an answer, will update with a solution when I find one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q8dkK/

Using the exact same code the script can display the pictures on jsfiddle but not "offline" so to say(when I have the files on my computer).

Comment: Are you sure you have the right path for the local pictures? Also, you seem to have some unmatched `</div>` on your HTML. Try running it against the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: And: jsfiddle is set to run the code "onload". Where's that js in your code? Try putting it inside `window.onload = function() { /* code here */ };`. Or use `$(document).ready(function(){ /* code here */ });` if you want to use jQuery (which you're including already).

Comment: I added window.onload like you suggested and it works now. Thank you for your help.